# Why do I have 2 Android SDK folders in my pc

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 2 Android folders in my pc.

1. is the one i though I was using in my `D drive`
2. another is on `C:\Users\rhsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

[image: screen shot of both sdk folders]

the noticeable differences are the main SDK folder has more folders inside it but the 2nd one has AVD manager and SDK manager in it , which I couldn't find in the main one.

Also, 2nd one has only android-24 in its platform and build-tool folders, whereas 1st one has a lot of them which I use.

So, what is the 2nd one used for? Can I delete it?

***Note: I am using android studio 3.5.3 and using latest platform android-29***

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1036320/android-folder-contains-2-sdk-folders

Comment: @RonS ironically, that link has an answer pointing back to an answer on here :D

Comment: @a_local_nobody the odds are astronomical xD

Comment: @RonS well I am confused because the 2nd one has avd manager and sdk manager in it. but the main one doesn't have them .

Comment: Look at the date modified...

Answer (score 0):

in D drive you can point your sdkmanager and c drice app data inside generate current sdk file path. in this file path we can store our sdk data and emulatter data ..... etc.

Comment: Cannot understand what this answer means

Comment: in simpal word D drive is your sdk path and C drive is your android studio process and storage directory

Comment: you can changed D drive data every where but when android studio download c drive androidstudio data automatically created if you delete c drive data it's package generate once again